# graphql mutation dosen't return nesetd fields

Tags: graphql, prisma

how can i return the nested fields from a mutation while preserving the type name

am using `prisma` with `graphql-yoga` on the backend

```js
async createComment(parent, args, ctx, info) {
    console.log(args);
    const comment = await ctx.db.mutation.createComment(
      {
        data: {
          ...args,
          user: {
            connect: {
              id: ctx.request.userId
            }
          },
          item: {
            connect: {
              id: args.itemId
            }
          }
        }
      },
      info
    );

    console.log(comment);

    ctx.pubsub.publish('PUBSUB_NEW_COMMENT', { newComment: comment });

    return comment;
 }
```

the mutation response dosent return the nested fields in my case `user` and `item` are `null`

Comment: your returning the 'result' of calling `ctx.db.mutation.createComment` we need to see this function.

Comment: Did you verify if `user` and `item` are actually being set in comment? There are chances that ids passed in `connect` are either undefined or incorrect.

Comment: i did fix that by adding the user and the item fields in gql on the client xD ,changing that also effects the payload that get sent to the subscription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did solve that by adding the `item` and `user` fields to `gql` mutation in the client

```
const COMMENT_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation COMMENT_MUTATION($text: String, $itemId: String) {
    createComment(text: $text, itemId: $itemId) {
      id
      text
      user { // adding user field here
        id
        name
      }
      item { adding item field here
        id
        title
        user {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

i don't understand how did that happen but because it affects the subscription payload too on the server
basically adding or removing fields from gql mutation change also the payload that go to the subscription